# Difference between openstack keypair create and ssh-keygen

Tags: ssh, openstack

I want to understand how exactly does the [openstack keypair create](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/keypair.html) command differs from ssh-keygen(both create a keypair ,right?). Also, what exactly happens when I provide a public key to the openstack keypair create command?

AFAIK, private key can't be derived from public key, so why is there an option to use an already available public key while creating a key pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, both `openstack keypair create` and `ssh-keygen` *can* (but note: not necessarily *do*) create a keypair that can be understood by an openssh-compatible ssh server.

They are generated in different ways, since the openstack client is written in Python whereas openssh is written in C. However, given a keypair, I don't believe there would be a way to tell whether it was generated by openstack or ssh-keygen. In other words, while you couldn't say they are "exactly the same", neither could you say that they are different in any meaningful sense.

When using `openstack keypair create --public-key <file>`, it assumes you want to make a public key available within your cloud service provider, for injecting into a virtual machine. It is only useful if you already have access to the private key. You would use this facility if you already have a private key generated with, say, `ssh-keygen`, and you want to use that key to ssh to a VM.